# how do i load the data in a page according to the user logged in?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I have a user login model with username and password. so when a user logs in I have created a session object to store the username.

I have this SQL query to select the user id from the database

```
 string query = "(select user_id from users where user_name='" + Session["usern"].ToString()+"')";
```

after this if i get the user id from this query I would use that id to get the data from the tables.
Please let me know what else should i add after the SQL query to get the query executed and even if I am doing anything wrong let me know !!

Comment: I way that could suggest is to store the username and user_id in the session variable. You could then use them for querying further.

Comment: @ Nikhil Baby i will just get the username from the login form, so i was trying to get the user_id from the username.Above query is used to get the user_id. suggest me a way to run the query and get the code executed.

Comment: if you're using the mvc provided user manager, then you should use `User.Identity.GetUserId()`. If you're not using the mvc provided user manager, I would suggest doing so if possible as it will save you a whole lot of time reimplementing things that are already provided to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following to query the database. For more details check the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2).

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "select user_id from users where user_name='" + Session["usern"] + "'";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

sqlConnection1.Close();
```